# Destroying View scope bean on redirect

Tags: jsf-2

I have a Managed Bean like the one given below. The method [**redirectToViewC**] returns to the same page (viewC.xhtml). I would like to **destroy the bean** once the action method execution is over. 
If I return **viewC?faces-redirect=true** , new instances of the bean is being cretaed by JSF2. Also Destroy method id not being called.

Let me know how to destroy view scoped bean if I return to the same page. 
Also is there a way to destroy view scoped beans from actionListener methods if I redirect to a different page using externalcontext.redirect() method

```
@ViewScoped

public class ViewC {

private String label ;
public ViewC(){
    System.out.println("Constructed View Bean C");
}
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    label = "This is view C";
    System.out.println("Initialized View Bean C");
}
@PreDestroy
public void release(){
    System.out.println("Destroy View Bean C");
}
public String redirectToViewC(){
    /*try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/Test/viewC.jsf?faces-redirect=true");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    return "viewC?faces-redirect=true";
}
public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}
public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

}
```